# JaVers Ignore Collection Order AND Report Duplicates in Collection

Tags: java, javers

When doing Collection Comparisons, the only way to ignore Order, is to use `ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET`. However, this will collapse duplicates in a collection.

Is there a way to Ignore the Collection Order, but care about duplicates?

i.e. `[a, b, b] != [a, b]` but `[a, a, b, b] == [a, b, a, b]`

Comment: If you don't mind creating copies or modifying the collections, you can use methods such as `retainAll`, or sort both and compare them.

Comment: Mena, thanks for the suggestions. Sorting is our planned fallback option. I was just hoping that there was built in functionality.